# Timestamping a slack notification from Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

```
 def trial = 'jobName'
 slackSend color: "good", message: "${trial} build successful"
```

The above code gives me the below Slack message-

```
jobName build successful
```

How do I timestamp the message so that I get the below message-

```
jobName build successful on dd/mm/yyyy
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the below piece of code-

```
def trial = 'jobName'
def date = new Date().format('dd/MM/yyyy')
slackSend color: "good", message: "${trial} build successful on " + date
```